# Is System.Data.DataTable in C# eligible for transactions?

Tags: c#, datatable, transactions

I am just a beginner in C# and now I work with table data only in the form of `System.Data.DataTable`, that is in-memory data. From my work elsewhere I know that there is such thing as transactions. Right now I need something like that in my work with DataTable. I found a `System.Transactions` namespace in the Visual Studio help. But I cannot dig whether it is applicable to DataTable. Neither could I find the answer in Google. Everywhere they are talking about transactions in C# concerning database engines like MS SQL, Oracle, ADO etc. So here I am with my probably very easy question: is System.Data.DataTable in C# eligible for transactions? For example, can I begin a transaction, add some rows to my DataTable, and then rollback? If this is possible, could you please give a sample code

Comment: Nope. But it's also not clear what you are trying to do. A DataTable is  just an in memory collectiom like and Array. If you would ask for DataSet it could make lil more sense. It is a collection of related tables. You could have a look at AcceptChanges available in DataTsble/DataSet. Maybe it comes close to what you need.

Comment: See: [AcceptChanges()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges?view=net-7.0) and [RejectChanges()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rejectchanges?view=net-7.0)

Comment: I don't think either `AcceptChanges` or `RejectChanges` promise transactionality.  They promise "I'm going to try to accept all the changes you have made" - I think.  I'd be really surprised if you get an "either everything completed successfully or nothing completed" promise out of them.  What are you trying to do.  Generally, DataTable and DataSet are a little antique, and if you want database behavior, you should really use a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks everyone for your prompt answer. Your suggestion about `AcceptChanges` and `RejectChanges` turned out to be exactly what I needed. I am inserting rows in a set of tables with parent-child relations. If no data is found for a certain subject for inserting in the last child table, then nothing should be inserted in any table at all. And now I can achieve this, by issuing `DataSet.AcceptChanges()` before starting a new subject, and issuing `AcceptChanges()` or `RejectChanges()` respectively after processing the subject completely